# Xamarin Android and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Tags: android, xamarin

I have created a "Blank App (Android)" project from the template in visual studio 2017 community.  If I add the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging version 1.1.2 nuget package and start/debug the project on my Android 7.0 device, everything works.  If I do the exact same thing but add version 2.0.0 (latest stable) version of the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging package, when I start/debug the application it immediately silently crashed the debugger.

Please help me figure out why this happening.

My assumption is that when the app loads its trying to find a missing reference but I have no way information to help me figure out which.

Updates:

Here's my VS and Java Information

```
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_d5719253\Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains adb in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_d5719253\Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
    Path contains ndk-stack in \. (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_d5719253\Android\JavaSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152).
[I:]:                     Found Xamarin.Android 8.2.0.15
[I:]:                     Found Android SDK. API levels: 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27
[I:]:                     Found Xamarin.Android 8.2.0.15
[I:sdk]:                  Runtime path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android
[I:sdk]:                  Framework path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0
[I:]:                     Tracking android devices started
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 17654e30506ed9d6 device
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 1 devices
[D:RunShellCommand]:      17654e30506ed9d6 getprop
[D:RunShellCommand]:      17654e30506ed9d6 getprop
[D:]:                     live player watcher: got device list from live player with 0 devices
[D:]:                     Tracking avd started
[D:]:                     avd watcher *.ini path: 'C:\Users\xxxx\.android\avd'
[D:]:                     avd watcher: got device list from avd with 8 devices
[E:]:                     an error occurred loading avd `Android_Accelerated_Nougat`, the system image does not exists
[E:]:                     an error occurred loading avd `Android_ARM_Nougat`, the system image does not exists
```

This is the debug log from 1.1.2 (it is much longer.  I've only attached the beginning)

```
Android application is debugging.
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/App3.App3/files/.__override__/App3.dll
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/App3.App3/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/App3.App3/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/App3.App3/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Mono.Android.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Java.Interop.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Collections.Concurrent.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Collections.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Threading.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Reflection.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Linq.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.Extensions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Reflection.Extensions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: MonoDroidConstructors [External]
03-13 11:18:02.561 E/Zygote  (30809): v2
03-13 11:18:02.561 I/libpersona(30809): KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10221
03-13 11:18:02.561 I/libpersona(30809): KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
03-13 11:18:02.563 E/Zygote  (30809): accessInfo : 0
...
...
...
```

This is the debug log from the 2.0.0 version (I've included the whole thing because it's short)

```
Android application is debugging.
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/App3.App3/files/.__override__/App3.dll
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/App3.App3/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/App3.App3/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/App3.App3/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/App3.App3/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/App3.App3/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Mono.Android.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Java.Interop.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Collections.Concurrent.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Collections.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Threading.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Reflection.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Linq.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.Extensions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Reflection.Extensions.dll [External]
```

This is the warning from the build of the 2.0.0 version.  There are no warnings in the 1.1.2 build.

```
Build succeeded.

"C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\App3\App3.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\App3\App3\App3.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
(_ResolveAssemblies target) -> 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1528,2): warning : Ignoring C:\Users\xxxx\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe\4.4.0\ref\netstandard2.0 as it is a Reference Assembly [C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\App3\App3\App3.csproj]

    1 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
```

Comment: Works well on my side, please show the log.

Comment: I have the build and debug log for both the 1.1.2 and 2.0.0 versions of MS logging framework.  The debug log abruptly ends for version 2.0.0 while the 1.1.2 version loads to completion.  I also have my visual studio details.  The only clue I get from any of this is a warning in the build log for 2.0.0 where it mentions a warning about ignoring system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.  Any idea how I get the post the logs?  They're relatively small but I can't post files here.

Comment: I've updated my original post.

Comment: I got a little more time today and found this:  https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1162, which sounds very much like my problem.  The post from "SvenEV commented on Jan 22" sounded good so I gave it a try.  No luck.  That did, however eventually lead me to https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/113718/android-error-with-signalr-core-could-not-load-assembly-system-memory-during-startup-registration.  Reading through this is suggests copying a referenced assembly directly into your obj/android/assets folder.  When I put system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe in there it works.

Comment: Now this isn't a solution but it at least points to the problem...  Any thoughts?